# UIView subclass ignores second touch

Tags: multi-touch, objective-c++

I'm making an iOS game, and I've written a UIView subclass that's supposed to catch touch events, and it works as intended for a single touch. However, if I'm already touching the screen with one finger then touch it with a second finger elsewhere, "touchesBegan" doesn't get called for the second touch.

Here's the implementation of the class: (Objective-C++)

```
#import "BATouchInput.h"

#include "BotsApp.h"

@implementation BATouchInput

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        std::cout << "touch started" << std::endl;
        BotsApp::getSingletonPtr()->touchDown(touch);
    }
    std::cout << "--------------" << std::endl;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    std::cout << [touches count] << std::endl;
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        BotsApp::getSingletonPtr()->touchMoved(touch);
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    for (UITouch* touch in touches) {
        BotsApp::getSingletonPtr()->touchUp(touch);
    }
}

@end
```

I'm creating an instance of this class through this code:

```
BATouchInput * touchRecieverView = [[BATouchInput alloc] initWithFrame: [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame]];
        [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview: touchRecieverView];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to set the value of [`multipleTouchEnabled`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/multipleTouchEnabled) property of your view to `YES` (the default value of this property is `NO`).