# Second touch is ignored

Tags: ios, swift

I have a class, `PanAndZoomView`, which inherits from `UIView` and is responsible for one of the screens in the iOS app that I am working on. There are other developers on the project and so many of the other screens in the app are not mine, and the PanAndZoomView is not the entry screen.

[I have multiple touch enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14789142/575530) for the view in the storyboard:

[image: xcode screenshot]

and I check that with a `print` statement in the following method

```swift
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    print("TouchesBegan, multipleTouchEnabled = \(self.multipleTouchEnabled)")
    let newTouches:Set<UITouch> = touches.subtract(self.touchesBeingTracked)
    for touch:UITouch in newTouches {
        self.initialTouches[touch] = touch.locationInView(self)
        self.initialScale = self.contentsView.transform.a
        self.initialTranslation = CGVector(dx: self.contentsView.transform.tx, dy: self.contentsView.transform.ty)
    }
    self.touchesBeingTracked.unionInPlace(touches)
    self.touchesBeingTrackedPeakCount = touchesBeingTracked.count
    self.segmentationView.containerTouchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)
}
```

However the PanAndZoomView only registers my first touch, i.e. the above method only fires once no matter how many fingers I touch the screen with.

My approach follows [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/multitouch_background/multitouch_background.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009541-CH5-SW3) and I'm using the same `PanAndZoomView` class in another project where it sees multiple touches without problem.

Why is the second touch ignored?

How do I diagnose my problem?

Comment: And `touches` contains only one `UITouch`?

Comment: Yes - when I put a `print` in the loop enumerating `touches` there is only one member

Comment: Could you try to call `super.touchesBegan(touches, withEvent: event)` in your function?

Comment: Thanks @Francescu, I've just tried that and it had no effect.

Comment: Could you try to call `super.` at the end of all the `touchesX` functions?

Comment: I've added them - still no second touch (thanks for trying though)

Comment: Sorry it didn't help! I guess you ensured the log prints `multipleTouchEnabled = true`? I don't see what could go wrong in your code. My advice would be to create an empty `UIView` subclass and adding only `touchesBegan` function with empty implementation (only the `print` inside). If it works then add back the code function by function to see which part bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with sub-views.

Although the `UIView` (`PanAndZoomView` in my code) handling the multiple touch events was marked in the storyboard as 'multiple touch enabled', its two sub-views were not. Marking them as multiple touch enabled fixes it so that now the PanAndZoomView gets the second touch.